# Sending a value from an HTML select to PHP with JavaScript on sript.js page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add the code from a table in an sql database into a div, depending on the result of the drop-down box and its not working! any help?

```
index.php
 <p> Choose Subject Area </p>
    <form action="">
        <select name="business area">
        <option value="">Programming</option>
        <option value="NAME">Web Design</option>
        <option value="NAME">TV&Film</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button id="Search" type="button">Search</button>
<?php
```

script.js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#Search').click(function(){
       $('#Results').append(
        <?php
            // generate sql query
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Form WHERE  Company_area="business_area";
            // execute query
            $result=sqlite_query($db,$sql);
            // get number of records found
            $numrows = sqlite_num_rows($result);
            echo "Number of records found: $numrows <br /><br />";
            //show results on screen
            while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {
                "<div>"
                    echo "Company Name: " . $row['Company_Name'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Company Area: " . $row['Company_area'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Description: " . $row['Description'] . "<br />";
                    echo "YouTube Link: " . $row['YouTube_Link'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Contact Name: " . $row['Contact_Name'] . "<br />";
                    echo "e-mail: " . $row['e-mail'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Facebook: " . $row['Facebook'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Twitter: " . $row['Twitter'] . "<br />";
                    echo "Website Address: " . $row['Website_address'] . "<br /><hr />";
                    "</div>"
                }
            ?>
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: The script.js is an actual JavaScript file? Your PHP won't work there, unless you configured apache to do that.

Comment: Your logic seems to be totally off? PHP is executed on the serverside before the HTML is even sent to the browser, so what you're doing simply isn't possible. You should probably be using ajax?

Comment: Dont use stuff like this, because every time php echoes a line with linebreak, and that line break will cause string error in javascript, .append requires html elements in form of string

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change `script.js` to `script.php` and include it in your page like this :

```
include "script.php";
```

Then execute javascript code using :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <?php 
    //php code here 
  ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Why -1 , explain and if you are right , i delete this answer ?

Comment: I did not pay attention, but the main contents of the response is correct,-1 is sever , any way thanks

Comment: I have removed my -1.

Comment: How is he going to populate the other options without using Ajax? The php will run before the drop down is selected.

Comment: @Jack try this example http://codepad.viper-7.com/8hJOnV , same here , but more php instructions are there